# Routing Error: No route matches {:controller=>"...", :action=>"..."}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying some code for simple search, and i can't run my code with this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:controller=>"welcome", :action=>"test"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This is my controller

```
  def search
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
    if @users
      redirect_to welcome_test_path(@users)
    else
      render root
    end
  end

  def test
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    logger.debug "user: #{@user}"
  end
```

Html:

```
  <%= form_tag :controller => 'welcome', :action => 'search', :method => 'post' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>                     
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
```

my routes

```
  get "uploads/new"

  get "micropost/new"

  get "user/new"
  get "user/saved"

  get "post/new"
  get "post/show"

  get "welcome/index"
  get "welcome/sucess"
  get "welcome/edit"
  get "welcome/test"
  root :to => "welcome#index"

  resources :users
  resources :relations,  only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts
  resources :uploads


  get '/users/:id', :to => 'welcome#sucess', :as => "user"  
  match '/relations', to: 'relation#create', via: 'post'
  match '/relations/:id', to: 'relation#destroy', via: 'delete'


  # Search
  match '/welcome/search', to: 'welcome#search', via: 'post'
  get '/welcome/test/:id', :to => 'welcome#test', :as => 'welcome_test'

  #Edit  
  match '/welcome/edit', to: 'welcome#edit', via: 'post'

  #Login & Logout
  match '/login', to: 'welcome#create', via: 'post'
  match '/logout' => 'welcome#destroy', as: :logout

  #Create
  match '/create', to: 'micropost#create', via: 'post'
  match '/signup', to: 'user#signup', via: 'post'
```

[image]

if I remove ":as => 'welcome_test" in my search routes, my app will run, but i can't get user id, so i must put it in my routes or try another way to get user id. Here, this is my log file if i remove `:as => 'welcome_test`:

```
Started POST "/welcome/search?method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-14 15:02:21 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ih08q0JhsrhjEm8G/3AEqnxZZZbw8VvM+VWGP1lUl/8=", "search"=>"sa1234", "method"=>"post"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username LIKE '%sa1234%' OR age LIKE '%sa1234%')[0m
user: [#<User id: 10, username: "sa1234", pass: "1234", created_at: "2014-10-14 09:12:44", updated_at: "2014-11-13 10:25:26", age: 18, image: "Hydrangeas.jpg">]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/welcome/test.10
Completed 302 Found in 3.0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/welcome/test.10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-14 15:02:22 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#test as 
Completed 404 Not Found in 1.0ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:43:in `test'
```

So, please help me to fix that !
I should remove `:as => 'welcome_test` and try another way to ger user_id, or fix my routes?